# Object of type (serializer name) is not JSON serializable

Tags: django, rest

I have a legacy system and a new one for classes (the kind you teach). In this part of the project I am trying to bring items from the old into the new but I keep running into "Object of type ThingOldClassSerializer is not JSON serializable" and I have yet to figure out why. There are no NULLs in the data. Some code:

`models.py`

```
class OldTemp(models.Model):
    legacy_user_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    legacy_title = models.CharField(max_length=250,)
    legacy_material_limit = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    legacy_handout_limit = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    legacy_handout_fee = models.FloatField()
    legacy_material_fee = models.FloatField()
    legacy_duration = models.FloatField()
    legacy_culture = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    legacy_topic = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    legacy_adult_only = models.BooleanField()
    legacy_heat_source = models.BooleanField()
    legacy_year = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    legacy_private_camp = models.BooleanField()
    legacy_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    instructor = models.CharField(default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.legacy_title
```

`serializers.py`

```
class ThingOldClassSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = OldTemp
        exclude = ['legacy_user_id', 'legacy_active']
```

`views.py`

```
class ThingOldToNewView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = OldTemp.objects.all
    serializer_class = ThingOldClassSerializer

    def get(self, request, pk, curr_old):
        oldclass = get_object_or_404(OldTemp, pk=pk)
        serializer = ThingOldClassSerializer(oldclass)
        return Response({'serializer': serializer, 'thingcurrentclass': oldclass})

    def post(self, request, pk, curr_old):
        oldclass = get_object_or_404(OldTemp, pk=pk)
        serializer = ThingOldClassSerializer(oldclass, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            self.check_object_permissions(request, oldclass)
            serializer.save(legacy_active=False)
            return redirect('home_page')
        return Response({'serializer': serializer, 'thingcurrentclass': oldclass})
```

The item displays just fine, but when I click a button to move the it into the new system (POST action) I get the error. Obviously I want this do other stuff when finished but I need to jump this hurdle first.

Comment: Does it error here? `serializer.save(legacy_active=False)` or here? `return Response({'serializer': serializer, 'thingcurrentclass': oldclass})` if the latter it is occurring because you are posting a JSON view while loading your serializer object. You need to turn it to a string or something that can be used. The error does not look to be with your models as there are no FKs

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. I thought it had something to do with the model when the fact is I forgot to give it a renderer. Adding:

```
renderer_class = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
template_name = ‘index.html’
```

Solved this part of the problem anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send serializer, or objects in "Response". you can only send dictionary in reponse which will later be converted to JSON. so,

```
return Response({'serializer': serializer.data, 'thingcurrentclass': oldclass.id})
```

and if you want to send whole data of oldclass and not just id then pass it to serializer and send serializer.data for it too

Answer (score 0):

in
`return Response({'serializer': serializer, 'thingcurrentclass': oldclass})`
you should return
`serializer.data` in "serializer" key instead...
they should look like this:
`return Response({'serializer': serializer.data, 'thingcurrentclass': oldclass})`